# OSM datasets auto rectification

Tags: qgis-plugins

Is there a plugins in QGIS that can auto rectify Openstreetmap vector area change sets as per aerial imagery

Comment: I would suggest you to describe more in detail what you need to do.

Comment: In JOSM I draw some buildings by using bing aerial source map and some buildings draw by using digitalglobe, so there is different crs between these source map, in QGIS i would like auto rectify all those buildings.